# How to do parallel execution of one single test case that is based on a large set of data

Tags: robotframework

I have written a single test case in robot framework that fetches data about more than 1000 locations from an excel sheet and runs each location. This whole execution takes more than 12 hours to complete. I want to minimize the execution time. Is there any possibility to execute it parallelly. I have gone through Pabot but that executes all test cases parallelly and I have only one test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for robot to split up a test case into multiple parallel threads or processes.

If you want multiple keywords to run in parallel, you'll have to rewrite your test suite to contain multiple tests, or create your own keywords to do work in parallel threads or processes.

Answer (score 1):

Datadriver works for me:

1. DataDriver https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver
2. pabot
3. https://pabot.org/PabotLib.html

how to run:

```
pabot --testlevelsplit  --pabotlib  ...
```